# has anybody tried to install CP210x USB to UART Bridge VCP Driver on Mac OSX 10.12?

Tags: macos, serial-port, driver, macos-sierra, uart

My mac doesn't recognize the driver after I installed the following driver from the Sillicon Labs:

https://www.silabs.com/products/development-tools/software/usb-to-uart-bridge-vcp-drivers

If anybody succeeded in installing the driver, I appreciate you for sharing how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://www.silabs.com/community/interface/forum.topic.html/cp210x_usb_to_uartb-LJMf) is said that "it appears the v5.x SiLabs driver is completely broken on macOS.

Fortunately the v4.x driver, which is included in the "Legacy MacVCP Driver" folder in the same download, works fine. Do note that you might have to install it twice for it to work, as the first install will just remove the existing driver. If it's installed, there should be a "SiLabsUSBDriver.kext" file in /Library/Extensions with a date created of June 16, 2017.